# Module showing up twice on the configuration page

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions

So I am creating a block extension on a community module. Its a simple one line change and I thought i did everything right. However, i went to the advanced configuration page and it shows up twice in the list. I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
app/etc/modules/Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext.xml
<config>
    <modules>
        <Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
              <Magestore_Affiliatepluscoupon />
            </depends>
        </Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext>        
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "list" of extensions in **System > Configuration > Advanced** is generated from all children node names of `modules` node. Any difference in the node name, including capitalization, will be interpreted as a unique module handle and will display in this list.

Comment: +1, deferring to the venerable @benmarks on this one - no set up script needed by the OP, no entry in core_resource exists.

Comment: I thought of that too...I am triple checking all of my capitalization, everywhere. However, the modules show up there as EXACTLY the same capitalization. I will upvote / check as answer if I find this to be the case.

Comment: I GOT IT! It wasn't capitalization it was in face a misspelling. One was spelled Afilliate the other Affiliate. I will upvote this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had this happen to me - for me it was because the record existed twice within `core_resource` table, with different capitalization. It's not counted as a duplicate, therefore it is displayed two times:

```
========name====================|=========version============
Blizzardlabs_Affiliateplusext   |           0.1
Blizzardlabs_AffiliatePlusExt   |           0.1
```

Comment: This module is so basic that it doesnt even need a setup script. Its a simple one line change that we wanted but didn't want to override the extension code. As such there is no information for it in the core_resource since no installation script was run.  Any other ideas? :\

Comment: In that case, @benmarks answer should be what you're looking for. The takeaway from both of our answers is - search for alternate spellings of your module elsewhere in your code.